# AJAX doesn't reload embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a drop down on my page allowing users to see past versions of API calls. When a user moves to a past version the javascript that is inserted onto the page isn't run. I am not currently using JQuery for my AJAX calls.

Please take a look. Goto the link, navigate to version 1, and then back to version 2. Notice how the embedded code (Code Snippet) doesn't appear.

http://devtest.indicee.com/api/reportapi/report/report-detail

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the script has already downloaded and ran.  It won't be downloaded and ran again.

You shouldn't be using `document.write` in this manner.  This is the source of your troubles.

If you must load in data this way, do it in JSON and output it with a single function at the top of your page.